# Extract a td value using XPath

Tags: html, xml, parsing, xpath

I need to extract values that are in a HTML cell table using XPath and I'd like not to use "positional" XPath string.

My code sample is something like this one

```
<body>
 <table>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table id="GridView5">
     <tr>...</tr>
     <tr>...</tr>
     <tr>
      <td>First Title</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
     <tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
```

I'm trying to use something like this XPath expression

```
//*[@id=”GridView5”]/*[td=”First Title”]/td[3]
```

to extract the value "**2**" from the above code

Suggestions? Examples?

Comment: Without a further distinctive feature of the target node it's impossible to circumvent using a _positional XPath_.

Comment: fixed in the question ... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//table[@id="GridView5"]/tr[td="First Title"]/td[3]
```

will select the third `td` child of the `tr` that has a `td` child with a string value of `First Title` within a `table` with an `id` attribute value of `GridView5`.

It uses a single positional selector for the requested `td` element because your markup affords no other way to differentiate the `td` that contains `2`, unless you allow an assumption that 2 comes after 1 or before 3 (treating either a label).  If the preceding or following `td` elements can serve as labels, then you could use the preceding or following sibling axis instead of the `[3]`.

```
//table[@id="GridView5"]/tr[td="First Title"]/td[.='1']/following-sibling::td[1]
```

but even here you'll need `[1]` to select only the *immediately* following sibling.